# How to go through 2 vectors in paralle using the same linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of double values which have the same length.

Is it possible to go through both lists by using a select statement and return the mean value of the difference between the elements from the same position?

Example :
`{1 2 3 4}`

`{1 1 1 1}`

I want to return `( (1 - 1) + (2 - 1) + (3 - 1) + (4 - 1) ) / 4 = 6 / 4 = 1.5`

Comment: It seems most people ignore the "parallel" in your question. But I will ask. Does it need to be in parallel? Do you really have so many numbers, that it could be optimized by running in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
listA.Zip(listB, (a, b) => a - b).Average();
```

Without .NET 4.0 and Zip, try

```
listA.Select((n, index) => n - listB[index]).Average()
```

Comment: Apologies if you're not using .NET 4.0 - in this case you won't have Zip.

Comment: @Rawling It's pretty easy to write yourself actually... if one were suitably motivated

Comment: @Servy I'd like to say that was an obvious comment to make, but to be honest it didn't cross my mind :)

Comment: @Rawling I just wrote a Zip implementation and added it to my post, since it seemed interesting.

Comment: @Servy Very nice. I'd even be tempted, in this case, to write something that throws if the two enumerations aren't the same length, although there's no nice way to check that beforehand without enumerating multiple times.

Comment: @Rawling The specs for the Zip method say it shouldn't do that.  The specs say it should do what my method does and just end when it reaches the end of the shortest enumeration, which is also what the library implementation does.  It's actually handy this way, for example you can zip an infinite enumeration that counts up from zero/one with something else to add an index (it's an academic example, but you see the point).  Also keep in mind that trying to count both enumerations to check their length would put you in hot water if you got anywhere near infinite sequences.

Comment: @Servy I suppose. I got the impression in this specific case that having the inputs be different lengths would be exceptional, but in a general-purpose Zip I can see the utility of it.

Comment: @Rawling In this case if I was worried that the lists were of a different size and wanted to throw if they were I'd check before calling Zip, rather than making a `Zip` implementation that added business logic for this one case.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 1 };

double result = list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => a - b).Average();
```

The result in 1.5 when I ran it.

---

Just because I felt like it and it came up in one of the other comments, here's my implementation of `Zip` that can run on C# 3.5.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Zip<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first
    , IEnumerable<T> second, Func<T, T, T> resultSelector)
{
    if (first == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("first");
    if (second == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("second");
    if (resultSelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("resultSelector");

    return ZipImpl(first, second, resultSelector);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> ZipImpl<T>(IEnumerable<T> first
    , IEnumerable<T> second, Func<T, T, T> resultSelector)
{
    IEnumerator<T> firstIterator = first.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator<T> secondIterator = second.GetEnumerator();
    while (firstIterator.MoveNext() && secondIterator.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return resultSelector(firstIterator.Current, secondIterator.Current);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're interested in technique (Zip method) or in result, but you will get same result from following code:

```
var arr1 = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
var arr2 = new[] {1, 1, 1, 1};
var res = (arr1.Sum() - arr2.Sum())/(double) arr1.Length;
```

Comment: Potentially no, actually.  This method could overflow while the other method might not, or this method could not overflow while the other does, depending on the values.  (This one is much more likely to overflow with lots of numbers.)  If you were to use decimal/double types instead changing the ordering of the addition would also affect the floating point error.

Comment: @Servy - good point, I forgot I'm not living in ideal world of pure math :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Enumerable.Range` to generate indexes does it (if you don't have the .NET 4.0's `Zip`)

```
var l1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var l2 = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
double result = Enumerable.Range(0, l1.Count)
    .Select(i => l1[i] - l2[i])
    .Average();
```

Comment: should set the range to the min of `l1.Count` and `l2.Count`, just to be safe.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, depends on the scenario.